# Why is there no output in jinja2 Loop?

Tags: jinja2

i try to loop over a dic in my jinja template. But i always get no output.

```
dic={"SERVICE1" : "tess","SERVICE2" : "test"}

with open(Path(Path.cwd()/"test.jinja")) as f:
template = Template(f.read()).render(data_nebula_docker)
print(template)
```

My template looks like this:

```
{% for item in dic %}
{{item}}
{% endfor %}
```

Normal Variablse are working fine. Does i have some basic misunderstanding?
Thx for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code. I'm going to assume the indentation issue in your `with` statement is just a copy-and-paste error, and that your code actually looks like:

```
with open(Path(Path.cwd()/"test.jinja")) as f:
    template = Template(f.read()).render(data_nebula_docker)
    print(template)
```

In your template you're referencing a variable `dic`, but you aren't passing this to the `render` method. You want:

```
from jinja2 import Template
from pathlib import Path

dic = {"SERVICE1": "tess", "SERVICE2": "test"}

with open(Path(Path.cwd() / "test.jinja")) as f:
    template = Template(f.read()).render(dic=dic)
    print(template)
```

Which produces:

```
SERVICE1

SERVICE2
```

You'll note that this only prints out the keys in your dictionary. When you iterate over a dictionary (in Jinja or Python), you get a list of keys. If you want `(key, value)` tuples instead, use the `.items()` method:

```
{% for item in dic.items() %}
{{item}}
{% endfor %}
```

Which produces:

```
('SERVICE1', 'tess')

('SERVICE2', 'test')
```

---

Separately, your use of `pathlib.Path` is a little convoluted; you can write instead:

```
with (Path.cwd()/"test.jinja").open() as f:
```

In the above:

- It's not necessary to wrap the result of `Path() / "string"` in a call to `Path()` (because it's already a `Path`)
- A `Path` object has an `open` method, so we can call `.open()` on the `Path` that results from `Path.cwd()/"test.jinja"`.

Although in this case, your `pathlib` based code isn't much of a win over:

```
with open("test.jinja") as f:
```